# Problem with "CFDataRef".

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets, casting

I have a problem with "CFDataRef.
I get the "data" field from a "kCFSocketDataCallBack.
"data" should correspond to a string received on the socket.
How do I convert, for example, in a NSString so I can put my text in a textbox??

Thank you very much

```
 static void
 AcceptDataCallback(CFSocketRef s,
 CFSocketCallBackType type, CFDataRef
 address, const void *data, void *info)
 {

 //my code for the textBox

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first try converting to NSData by casting it:

```
NSData * someData = (NSData*)address;
```

Then convert the NSData to NSString:

```
NSString * someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:someData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Or do it all at once:

```
NSString * someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData*)address encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

You may have to mess around with the encoding.

Comment: NSString * myString = @"My string"; CFDataRef myDataRef = (CFDataRef)[myString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];